# Switching activity without bringing my UI to top of phone UI stack

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an app with activity A,B and C and when my app is pushed into the background by another app or phone home button I want to switch from C to A. Then problem I have with the code below is that when I press the home button my app goes into the background but reappears in a few seconds on activity A. How can I switch but also stop A from popping back into the foreground after my app's UI is no longer visible ie when home is pressed.

```
   public void onTrimMemory(final int level) {
    if (level == ComponentCallbacks2.TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN) {
        Intent i=new Intent(this, A.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);   
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);

       finish();

       overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
       startActivity(i);

    }
```

Comment: What's the point of onTrimMemory here?  That has nothing to do with the home button.  It *may* be called when the home button is pressed, but it could be called anytime the framework wants to.  If you're using that to detect the home button, its horribly inaccurate with false positives and false negatives.

Comment: I use it to see if my app's UI is no longer visible, not just for home button

Comment: That's not what this function does.  It can be called while you're in foreground, and multiple times when you're in background.  It may also not be called at all if the system thinks it has enough resources.  It's the wrong place to put this code.  If you want to know if an Activity is no longer foreground, use the onStop function.

Comment: In fact the documentation itself says "You should never compare to exact values of the level, since new intermediate values may be added -- you will typically want to compare if the value is greater or equal to a level you are interested in."